# javascript wont let me store a form value into a var

Tags: javascript, forms, var

I've been tryna do this simple danged var assignment all night, now its too late >=[.

```
<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JavaScript">
var P;
function save(f1)
{
    P = parseFloat(document.getElementByID('loan1').value);
}


<form name = "form" action = "mortgagecalc.html" id="f1" onSubmit="check_form(form);">
    <b>Loan Amount</b>
    <input type = "text" name = "loan" size = "15" id="loan1" onchange="save(form)"><br>

</form>
```

and every single time I tab out of the loan field the console gives me:

```
Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function
```

for the line P = parse...

I tried everything!!I followed the examples perfectly. What is up with javascript variables never working for me??? UGHHHHHHH

Comment: First thing... `getElementByID` must be `getElementById`!

Comment: Look in the browser's error console to see the error messages.

Comment: @Juhana I already said in my question the error I was receiving from the console. that didn't tell me I had a typo on getElementById though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have a typo error

```
parseFloat(document.getElementByID('loan1').value);
```

should be

```
parseFloat(document.getElementById('loan1').value);
```

Comment: dang. I unfortunately probably never would have seen that.

Answer (score 2):

You just made a typo, it's `getElementById`, not `getElementByID`. What you wrote doesn't exist (=undefined) and thus will trigger an error that undefined is not a function.